# Show that a graph G is regular

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

the question is

A connected graph G with 4 edges and 4 vertices has 2 vertices of degree 2. show that G is Eulerian if then G is regular

Comment: There aren't that many graphs with $4$ edges and $4$ vertices. Even fewer of them have at least two vertices with degree $2$.  Have you tried drawing them?

Comment: yes I'm just not sure how to show the proof

Comment: i drew 4 vertices in a square shape, 3 of the vertices form a triangle on the right corner, and the last vertex (the top left one) is connected to the bottom right vertex. a eulerian graph is one where each path can only be taken once, and a regular graph is a graph where all the vertices have the same neighbors...how would i write a proof showing that this graph which i have drawn follows both guidelines?

Comment: "G is Eulerian if then G is regular" does not make sense. Did you mean "if G is Eulerian then G is regular"?

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is connected, so every vertex has degree at least $1$. Since there are $4$ edges, the sum of degrees of the vertices must be $8$. So the four vertices have degrees (a) $\{1,2,2,3\}$ or (b) $\{2,2,2,2\}$ . In case (a), the single-degree vertex must connect to the 3-degree vertex (which connects to all vertices) and the other edge connects the two degree-two vertices. In case (b), to maintain connectivity, $G$ must be a cycle graph. These two graphs look like this:

[image]

$G$ is Eulerian if there is a trail in the graph that includes every edge and finishes at the starting vertex. In case (a), the vertex with degree one cannot be part of such a trail. In case (b), the trail clearly exists as the graph is $C_4$. (b) is regular and (a) is not; therefore the correspondence between Eulerian and regular is proven.

In fact the specification that two of the edges have degee $2$ is unnecessary, as this cannot in any case be avoided.